# How do I write a generator's output to a text file?

Tags: python, generator

The `difflib.context_diff` method returns a generator, showing you the different lines of 2 compared strings. How can I write the result (the comparison), to a text file?

In this example code, I want everything from line 4 to the end in the text file.

```
>>> s1 = ['bacon\n', 'eggs\n', 'ham\n', 'guido\n']
>>> s2 = ['python\n', 'eggy\n', 'hamster\n', 'guido\n']
>>> for line in context_diff(s1, s2, fromfile='before.py', tofile='after.py'):
...     sys.stdout.write(line)  # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
*** before.py
--- after.py
***************
*** 1,4 ****
! bacon
! eggs
! ham
  guido
--- 1,4 ----
! python
! eggy
! hamster
  guido
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has nothing to do with generators or context_diff.  It's basically "How do I write to a file?"  You should read http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
with open(..., "w") as output:
    diff = context_diff(...)
    output.writelines(diff)
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines) for `file.writelines()`.

Explanation:

1. `with` is a context manager: it handles closing the file when you are done. It's not necessary but is good practice -- you could just as well do

   ```
   output = open(..., "w")
   ```

   and then either call `output.close()` or let Python do it for you (when `output` is collected by the memory manager).
2. The `"w"` means that you are opening the file in write mode, as opposed to `"r"` (read, the default). There are various other options you can put here (`+` for append, `b` for binary iirc).
3. `writelines` takes any iterable of strings and writes them to the file object, one at a time. This is the same as `for line in diff: output.write(line)` but neater because the iteration is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open(filepath, 'w')
for line in context_diff(s1, s2, fromfile='before.py', tofile='after.py'):
    f.write("%s\n" %line)

f.close()
```